# Lua: exit event

Tags: logging, lua, exit

I'm writing library for logging in Lua with some advanced features like log updating. Are there any exit event in pure Lua? I'm going to use it for avoiding cursor hides after process exit.

Comment: When Lua 5.2+ interpreter exits, it executes all `__gc` metamethods.  For example: `$ lua -e "t = setmetatable({},{__gc=function()print'Hi'end})"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Egor wrote in the comment, you can use `__gc` metamethod to catch the event of the final garbage collection in Lua 5.2+; you'll need to use undocumented `newproxy` in Lua 5.1. The following code should work in Lua 5.1 and later interpreters:

```
local m = {onexit = function() print("exiting...") end}
if _VERSION >= "Lua 5.2" then
  setmetatable(m, {__gc = m.onexit})
else
  m.sentinel = newproxy(true)
  getmetatable(m.sentinel).__gc = m.onexit
end
```

Comment: No, I need a *pure* way to do it: if I will `killall lua`, then script will be terminated and no event will be called.

Comment: @MalyutinEgor - Lua can do nothing against killing its process :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pure, but as Egor said there is no other way at the Lua level to do this.